# JPA EclipseLink oneToMany Derived Ids Fail

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, foreign-key-relationship

Hello I'm trying to make an example of persistence of a OneToMany relationship in which I get the following error:

```
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [entitys.OrderItemPK] and those of the entity bean class [class entitys.OrderItem] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
```

Note: I'm using EclipseLink and MySQL DB

[image: The database design]

The entities:

```java
@Entity
public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idOrder")
    private Integer idOrder;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "orderText")
    private String orderText;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerOrder")
    private Collection<OrderItem> orderItemCollection;

    public CustomerOrder() {
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderItemPK.class)
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected OrderItemPK orderItemPK;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemDesc")
    private String itemDesc;

@Id
@ManyToOne(optional = false)    
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="idOrder", referencedColumnName="idOrder"),
    @JoinColumn(name="ItemNumber", referencedColumnName="ItemNumber")
})      
//@JoinColumn(name = "idOrder", referencedColumnName = "idOrder", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private CustomerOrder customerOrder;
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

    public OrderItem() {
        this.orderItemPK = new OrderItemPK();
   }
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class OrderItemPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idOrder")
    private int idOrder;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemNumber")
    private int itemNumber;

    public OrderItemPK() {
    }
}
```

The test Source:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    // Fill the items fileds
    OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
    item.setItemDesc("Item Text");

    // Fill the orders fields
    CustomerOrder order = new CustomerOrder();
    order.setOrderText("Order text");

    // Fill the relationship fields
    order.getOrderItemCollection().add(item);
    item.setCustomerOrder(order);        

    em.persist(order);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How are you setting the values within the OrderItem's OrderItemPK?  With these mappings, the idOrder needs to be set using the value from the referenced CustomerOrder manually, which I'm guessing you aren't doing.  You might want to look into JPA 2.0's derrived Ids, which allow you to specify the OrderItem.customerOrder relationship MapsId("idOrder") so that JPA handles setting the value for you.  Otherwise you need to persist your CustomerOrder and flush, obtain the idOrder value and set it in the OrderItem before it can be persisted.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it. I was able to persist the object by setting the id in PK object, but i want to persist the object collection in one step.

I'll let you know how it was .-

Comment: Try IdClass but I did not succeed, I got another error, edit the post with the current state

Comment: Well. manged to solve the problem by using the annotation:     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<OrderItem> orderItemCollection;

Comment: What you posted is a mash up of a few things that are not meant to work together.  You use a PK class OR an embeddedId, not both, and if you have an EmbeddedId, you cannot mark other mappings as the ID - these should give you exceptions/warnings when the persistence unit loads.  If you are going to use an EmbeddedId class/mapping within your entity, use the mapsId annotation on your relationship - it tells JPA that your relationship will control one or more of the values within the embedded instance, so you do not need to manually set it.

Comment: Could you please show me how to set the entities to work with PK CLass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i managed to solve the problem by removing idClass annotation and adding the @MapId

heres the final code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "idOrder")
  private Integer idOrder;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "orderText")
  private String orderText;     

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Collection<OrderItem> orderItemCollection;

 public CustomerOrder() {
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "OrdersItems")
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @EmbeddedId
  protected OrderItemPK orderItemPK;
  @Basic(optional = false)

  @Column(name = "itemDesc")
  private String itemDesc;

  @MapsId("idOrder")    
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)    
  @JoinColumn(name = "idOrder", referencedColumnName = "idOrder", nullable = false)    
  private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

  public OrderItem() {
    this.orderItemPK = new OrderItemPK();
  }

@Embeddable
public class OrderItemPK implements Serializable {
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "idOrder")
  private int idOrder;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "itemNumber")
  private int itemNumber;

  public OrderItemPK() {
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    // Fill the order item
    OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
    item.getOrderItemPK().setItemNumber(1);
    item.setItemDesc("Product Name");

    // Fill the order
    CustomerOrder order = new CustomerOrder();
    order.setOrderText("Testing");

    // Create relationship
    order.getOrderItemCollection().add(item);
    item.setCustomerOrder(order);

    // Persist
    em.persist(order);
    em.getTransaction().commit();        
}
```

But i can't get it work with IdClass, here's the source

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderItemPK implements Serializable {

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "idOrder")
  private Integer idOrder;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "ItemNumber")
  private Integer itemNumber;

  public OrderItemPK() {
  }

@Entity
@IdClass(OrderItemPK.class)
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "itemNumber")
   private Integer itemNumber;

   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "itemDesc")
   private String itemDesc;

   @MapsId("idOrder")    
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)    
   @JoinColumn(name = "idOrder", referencedColumnName = "idOrder", nullable = false) 
   private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

   public OrderItem() {
   }

  @Entity
  public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idOrder")
    private Integer idOrder;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "OrderText")
    private String orderText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<OrderItem> orderItemCollection;

    public CustomerOrder() {
        this.orderItemCollection = new ArrayList();
    }
```

Comment: the approved answer is probably not the best spot to post code that isn't working.  You are using MapsId which is used to point to an Id mapping rather then just marking the relationship as an ID.  You also need to change the OrderItemPK's idOrder to be called customerOrder.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much for your help, I was finally able to run the example with the advice you gave me.
I have still a question ...
I find it much easier to use the MapsId annotations, but this type of annotation, seems not to work in a web environment (using GlassFish 4.1 and JTA) I get a null pointer exception

Comment: MapsId is not the problem and should work anywhere.  That said, I can't say what the root cause of the NPE (other then it should have nothing to do with mapsId) without more information.

Comment: I could find the fix to my problem. The problem was in the PK class, change the data type int to Integer and then the error appeared on the method hashCode(). Thank you very much for your help again

Answer (score 0):

Use MapsId in OrderItem:

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected OrderItemPK orderItemPK;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemDesc")
    private String itemDesc;

    @MapsId("idOrder")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)       
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOrder", referencedColumnName = "idOrder")
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;
}
```

An alternative is to remove the embedded id and use an ID class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderItemPK.class)
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "itemNumber")
    private int itemNumber;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemDesc")
    private String itemDesc;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)       
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOrder", referencedColumnName = "idOrder")
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;
}

public class OrderItemPK implements Serializable {
    //name of the relation in the entity, but same type as the CustomerOrder PK.
    int customerOrder;

    int itemNumber;

    public OrderItemPK() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot that for the PKClass example, the OrderItemPK needs to replace the "private Integer idOrder;" with "private Integer customerOrder;".